# How to insert a popup inside a table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html and would like to wrap a table cell (1x1, with length and width easily editable) around the onclick function pop-up.
This includes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
This may eventually include several columns in one row, with multiple popups, so if possible please make this adaptable.

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction901() {
  var popup901 = document.getElementById("myPopup901");
  popup901.classList.toggle("show901");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup901 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #feb330;
  "

}


/* The actual popup */

.popup901 .popuptext901 {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -31px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup901 .popuptext901::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup901 .show901 {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<h4>&nbsp;</h4>
<h5>&nbsp;</h5>
<h6>&nbsp;</h6>
<div class="popup901" onclick="myFunction901()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams
  <span class="popuptext901" id="myPopup901">2016, 2018: 22</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There appears to be no table in your markup.  Please clarify as working with a table is sometimes different than the markup you provide.

Comment: Do you have anything you have attempted to solve this (associated with the markup you provide somehow) that we can help you with?  What do you mean "around the onclick function pop-up" - near it, a table cell (`td`) around that markup? (if so DO that in the markup you provide).  Please help us help you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is the best way, but i was able to do it declaring "**n**" inside your function,

```
function myFunction901(n) {
```

then for each onclick function in each popup you assing a number,

example:

```
onclick="myFunction901(1)"
```

lastly in your function i wrote the element id get as:

```
var popup901 = document.getElementById("myPopup90"+n);
```

so it reads that number and get the matching id.

You can then style the popup area with css to make em as you want (more square like etc.).

Check the code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup901 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#feb330;"
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup901 .popuptext901 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -31px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup901 .popuptext901::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup901 .show901 {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<h4>&nbsp;</h4>
<h5>&nbsp;</h5>
<h6>&nbsp;</h6>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="popup901" onclick="myFunction901(1)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams
      <span class="popuptext901" id="myPopup901">2016, 2018: 22</span>
      </div>
    </td>
        <td>
      <div class="popup901" onclick="myFunction901(2)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams
      <span class="popuptext901" id="myPopup902">2016, 2018: 22</span>
      </div>
    </td>
        <td>
      <div class="popup901" onclick="myFunction901(3)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams
      <span class="popuptext901" id="myPopup903">2016, 2018: 22</span>
      </div>
    </td>
        <td>
      <div class="popup901" onclick="myFunction901(4)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams
      <span class="popuptext901" id="myPopup904">2016, 2018: 22</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction901(n) {
  var popup901 = document.getElementById("myPopup90"+n);
    popup901.classList.toggle("show901");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

is this what you meant?